# Getting twitter friends number with Python

Tags: python, twitter, request

I need to get twitter friends from an user. With twitter "***friends***" I mean user **A follows user B**, and also **user B follows A**. 
Ok, so my idea was getting a list of people who are followed by user A, and if they are followed by user B, it increases numFriends.
First part works fine, but when I do that second request it falls apart and throws me an ugly 'error 400' :(
I read about the restrictions of twitter and all that, but it seems weird that second request so I don't know if it's doing ok.

Thank you in advance, I'm a noob at python and twitter api, and my mother tongue is not english, so I really hope it is everything clear. I will thank any help about this.

Here is the code :)

```
def getNumFriends(user):

    dataUser=0
    numFriends=0
    url ="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=%s&count=5000"%(user.screen_name)
    auth = OAuth1(getConsumerKey(), getConsumerSecret(), getAccessToken(), getAccessTokenSecret())
    response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        dataUser = response.json()
        userIDs = dataUser['ids']
    else: 
        print "Error code %s" %response.status_code
    #Here comes the problem :S
    for friend in userIDs:
        url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/show.json?source_id=%s&target_screen_name=%s"%(friend, user)
        response = requests.get(url, auth)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            dataCompare = response.json()    
            mutualfriends = dataCompare['relationship']['target']['followed_by']
            if mutualfriends =='true':
                numFriends=numFriends+1
        else:
            print "First request OK. Second request error code %s" %response.status_code
            break       
    return numFriends
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, there are only a couple of minor mistakes. The error code 400, "bad request", does not give you very concrete info, but it tells you that something in the way you've written the `url` is wrong.

It should be:

```
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/show.json?source_id=%s&target_screen_name=%s"%(friend, user.screen_name)
```

i.e it should be `user.screen_name` instead of user.

Besides, the second argument of `requests.get()` is not `auth`, thus you should specify always the name of the argument,

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
```

which wasn't the case in your second call.

BTW, just curious, any reason why you are not using a library like `twython`?

Hope it helps.

** EDIT after comments: **
There was another minor mistake in the code. Note that your variable `mutualfriends` is already boolean, in order to check its value you can do it like this,

```
if mutualfriends:
    ...
```

BTW, to check the type of a variable,

```
print(type(mutualfriends))
```

Comment: Ok, that works nice! I tried now, but it doesn't increases numFriends, is still numFriends=0. Ah, I had some trouble installing twython so, that why xD Anyway, ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Ok, there was another minor mistake, I'm updating the answer. De nada!